# Own memory management in Objective-C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, objective-c++, nsobject

For C++ code I can manage memory on my own  by using placement new/delete operator and their arraycounterparts.

Now I‘d like to use my memory manager also for Objective-C code. I thought about replacing NSObject‘s `alloc:` and `dealloc:` methods, but `poseAsClass:` doesn‘t work any longer. So: How can I force it using my memory manager?
Or am I completly on a wrong path?

Comment: What kind of obnoxious philistine are you?  No programmer should ever want to do their own memory management!  That's what carefully optimized garbage collectors are for!  And everybody knows that lack of garbage collection and the need to do any sort of memory management is what makes C++ an awful and horribly outdated language.  *shakes head in disbelief*

Comment: Apple is holy. Never, never ever reimplement their holy, well-designed, perfectly written code!

Comment: BTW, my previous post should be read as being very sarcastic, in case it wasn't obvious.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think you're on a wrong path - the fundamentals of how the reference counting (and indeed garbage collection on non iOS devices) work are, I suspect, too embedded into the language implementation to make this a realistic possibility.

I also don't understand *why* you'd want to do this, unless you've a particular fondness for re-inventing wheels.